# flex-box box-sizing: border-box not working

Tags: css, flexbox, border-box, box-sizing

As title says:

```css
.cnr{
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px red solid;
}
.cnr > div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1em solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cnr > .closed{
  width: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow:   0;
  min-width:   0;
  min-height:  0;
}
```

```html
<div class="cnr">
  <div>
    open
  </div><div class="closed">
    closed
  </div>
</div>
```

Can't closed the second div using `width: 0` because of padding and border.

What do?

I don't know what more details can I add. It's a container set to `display: flex`. Each flex item has a border and padding and some (text) content. There are 2 of them in total. Then some of them will be closed using width: 0, and to closed the border and padding as well. `box-sizing: border-box` is used.

But it doesn't work. Thank you.

Edit: ok, sorry for not explaining clearly, but width needs to be animated, that's why the padding needs to be there when the animation is playing, and I would like to not animate the padding as well if possible.

Comment: change your selector for `.closed` to `.cnr > .closed` and add `padding: 0;`?

Comment: can't you use `display: none` ?

Comment: I can't, because I want to animate the width. And using `display: none` doesn't fix `box-sizing` not working...

Comment: `padding: 0` is an option, but I want my animation to not change padding if possible.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the duplicate. I just assumed the problem was caused by flex-box. Looks like it's the box-sizing and padding.

Comment: You could add an extra wrapper to animate the width: https://jsfiddle.net/ucc4sa97/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `:not`:

```
.cnr>div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cnr>div:not(.closed) {
  border: 1em solid;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```js
$('.cnr').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('div').toggleClass('closed');
})
```

```css
.cnr {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.cnr>div{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cnr>div:not(.closed) {
  border: 1em solid;
  padding: 1em;
}

.cnr>.closed {
  width: 0;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cnr">
  <div>
    open
  </div>
  <div class="closed">
    closed
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Might be worth separating the padding property to be the only one within the `.cnr>div:not(.closed)` selector, and still having the `overflow`, `border` and `box-sizing` within the original selector, just incase there's ever a time where the closed one still needs access to those properties.